# Count total column with type on laravel eloquent

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I have users table and i want count total of the status..
I dont know how to do it on laravel here my example table:

I want count total of active, disable, and pending status
So i have `3 active status`, `2 disabled status`, and `1 pending status` 
How to do it ?

```
id  name  status
1   A     active
2   B     active
3   C     disabled
4   D     active
5   E     disabled
6   F     pending
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use laravel [groupBy](https://laravel-recipes.com/laravel-eloquent-groupby-and-also-return-count-of-each-group/) method here

```
\DB::table('users')
       ->select('status', \DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
       ->groupBy('status')
       ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **group by** using the count method

```
\DB::table('users')
    ->select('status', \DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
    ->groupBy('status')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try this

```
$users = App\User::groupBy('status')
->select(\DB::raw('count(*) as total'),'status')
->get();
```